# Initialising unknown ranged array in class C++

Tags: c++

I've got a beginner's problem:

```
class Snake
{
public:
    int mapa[][];
    Snake(int szer,int wys)
    {
        mapa[szer][wys];
    }
};
```

I'm trying to do something like above(create array with size defined in the constructor), but it seams to be not possible in C++. 
Is there any way to do this work?

Comment: Use `std::vector` and a member initializer.

Comment: Don't use naked C-style arrays - this is C++ - use std::vector.

Comment: http://jcatki.no-ip.org/fncpp/Resources

Comment: -1 for no prior research whatsoever

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > ...;
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on you needs you can either use a `std::vector<std::vector<T> >` or a class giving a `std::vector<T>` an interface of a two dimensional areay. For tha latter you would overload `operator[]()` to return an object giving a subrange of the internal `std::vector<T>` the felling of an array itself. If you just want to use the subscriot operator, returning a `std::vector<T>::iterator` would work but it wouldn't expose, e.g., `begin()` and `end()` iterators.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use the `new` keyword, you would have to do a 2-step initialization:

```
int **mapa;
Snake(int szer,int wys)
{
    mapa = new int*[szer];
    for (int i = 0; i < szer; i ++)
        mapa[i] = new int[wys];
...
```

Comment: Those are not "standard arrays". They are pointers to dynamically-allocated blocks of memory (a lot of them)

Comment: True. Perhaps I should edit to "messy pointer magic" instead.